# Laravel [vendor.installer.welcome] not found and redirect to localhost:8000/install when running laravel app

Tags: php, laravel

When I start to run my laravel app that is cloned from my gitlab repository, my laravel app redirect to localhost:8000/install (it redirects to "/install") and I am getting this error.

```
[2021-11-13 14:15:54] local.ERROR: View [vendor.installer.welcome] not found. {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): View [vendor.installer.welcome] not found. at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\staging_prj\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\View\\FileViewFinder.php:137)
[stacktrace]
```

I am googling on it so many times and any solution or idea won't get.

Comment: Hmm looks like the View is not found you try to access, but the path to the "welcome" blade is strange.. Try to run `composer update` `php artisan optimize:clear`. And what about the redirect to the /install route? Is it some custom logic or do you need to run an installation flow?

Comment: Check if `resources/views/vendor/installer/welcome.blade.php` file exists.

Comment: Check that you are on right branch.